# Onclick event is performed even on long clicking

Tags: android, listview

I am using an `ExpandableListView lv`. This is what i have.

```
ExpandableListView lv=(ExpandableListView )findViewById(....);
lv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener(){
@Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int gp, int cp, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //perform action    
        return true;
    }
});

lv.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {     
        ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        customMenu.show(v);
        //do other stuff
        contextMenu=null;
    }
});
```

When i long click on a child item, the `customMenu.show(v)` is called, and when i lift my finger off, its `OnClickListener` is called. 
Similarly, on long pressing and then releasing the finger on a group item, its `ContextmenuListener` is called and then the group expands to show the child items. Is this normal behavior? How do I prevent this?

I actually want to do stuff on `long Click` on a list item. Returning `true` on `longClickListener` works properly (consumes the click event).
But I also need to get item's id, group and child position, which is provided via `ContextMenuInfo` in the `contextmenu` listener only.

Comment: Shouldn't you call lv.registerForContextMenu() instead?

Comment: Well, when i tried to actually show the contextmenu by adding some menu items in it, it worked properly. But I dont want to do that. I want to show my own menu instead, like in the given code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set a global boolean such as

```
boolean isLongClick = false;

public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if(isLongClick == false){ // this checks to see if it was long clicked
        // Perform your action here
    }
    isLongClick = false; // resetting longClick to false after bypassing action
}

public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
    isLongClick = true; 
    //perform other action here
    return false;
}
```

What this does is runs two action listeners one for click and one for long click.
if a user long clicks on the object, it sets the boolean to true, thus blocking the action from 
being performed in the onClickListener, but the onClickListener still fires no matter what, so 
we make sure to reset the boolean in that method, so that after the long press, the item will then again accept a single press.

Granted this silently implies that you would need to get the id of the item pressed etc. But this methodology works like a charm. I have just implemented it in an app for a pop up menu. 
I wanted two different menus to pop up depending on whether the user single pressed or long pressed on the anchor. Thus if they pressed quickly it would pop up an (open with) menu, if long pressed it would pop up a menu for (share to , edit, delete) etc.

Comment: i hope you find solution better than this .

Answer (score 6):

Ensure that

```
@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        return true; //<-- this should be TRUE, not FALSE   
    }
```

is returning `true`. returning `false` seems to continue the method calling into `onClick()`.

This solution worked for me, at least. `return false` was the default for me when I auto-generated the code in eclipse, and I didn't think to change it.